# Finding similar phases

Tags: pandas, string, nlp, similarity

How can I find similar phases within a large list of phases (i.e. tweets, or movie reviews)?

For example, `'I like chocolate'` is similar to `'I like chocolate bar'` and `'I like mango'`; same as `'I ate apple'` vs `'I ate apples'`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Text':  ['I like chocolate',
                  'I like chocolate bar',
                  'I ate apple',
                  'I ate apples',
                  'I like mango',
                  'I can swim']  
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Text'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `fuzzywuzzy` package, use `extractWithoutOrder` the unsorted version of `extract` to find the similarity between strings:

```
# pip install fuzzywuzzy
# conda install -c conda-forge fuzzywuzzy 
from fuzzywuzzy.process import extractWithoutOrder as extract
from operator import itemgetter

ratio = df["Text"].apply(lambda s: list(map(itemgetter(1), extract(s, df["Text"]))))
out = pd.DataFrame(ratio.tolist(), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

```
>>> out
     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  100   95   44   43   64   86
1   95  100   86   86   86   86
2   44   86  100   96   49   38
3   43   86   96  100   48   45
4   64   86   49   48  100   36
5   86   86   38   45   36  100
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. I notice 5x5 comparison is fast; 10x10 is around the same, but 100x100 takes a long time. How best can I run this against 10,000 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `soundex` from `jellyfish`,same output should have similar phases

```
import jellyfish
df.Text.map(jellyfish.soundex)
0    I422
1    I422
2    I314
3    I314
4    I425
5    I252
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find similarity between sentences/phrases, a simple technique is to use [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) model and apply similarity computation technique such as [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). This can be improved further by using [word vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding).